# Adding a comment section form to my Django app

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I get 2 different errors the first one is

### Django Model IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:

I checked the solution for this, people said I've to make my FK attributes null = true and blank = true
so this solved that.
The second error I got after that was in my views.py

### 'CommentForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

### My Views.py file:

```
def project(request, pk):
    form = CommentForm()
    project = ProjectModel.objects.get(id=pk)
    contextt ={
        "project": project,
        "form":form,
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        form.save()
        return redirect(request, "/dashboard")
    else:     
        return render(request, "projects.html", contextt)
```

### and my Models.py:

```
class ProjectModel(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="video/%y", validators=[file_size])
    ProjectName = models.CharField(max_length=50, )
    ProjectDescription = models.TextField(max_length=1000,)
    Project_Background_picture = models.ImageField(
    upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, default='/static/img/default.png')
    Approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Goal = models.DecimalField(
    decimal_places=3, max_digits=6, blank=True, null=True)
    Pledges = models.DecimalField(
    decimal_places=3, max_digits=6, blank=True, null=True)
    Number_of_investors = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    FirstReward = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default=' 10$ ')
    SecondReward = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default=' 25$')
    ThirdReward = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default='50$')
    FourthReward = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default='100$ +s')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption

class comment(models.Model):
    ProjectModel = models.ForeignKey(
    ProjectModel, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    CommentBody = models.TextField(default='comment here!', max_length=1000 )
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def _str_(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.ProjectModel.caption, self.name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def project(request, pk):
    form = CommentForm()
    project = ProjectModel.objects.get(id=pk)
    contextt ={
        "project": project,
        "form ":form ,
    }   
    if request.method == 'POST'  :
        form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form= form.save(commit=False)        #new line
            form.ProjectModel = project     #new line
            form.save()
            return redirect("/dashboard")
    else:     
       return render(request, "projects.html", contextt)
```

Comment: ## Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: POST '/project/2'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: POST '/project/2'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name. ##
 This gave me this new error, Even tho it did add the comment to the database but without a specific project, it just added a dumb comment that doesn't exist in any project

Comment: @MohamedMedhat your redirect is wrong, you don't need to put the request as an argument in it.

Comment: the " ## Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: POST '/project/2'>"  error is about your URLS ,take a look at this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107642/noreversematch-at-signup-reverse-for-wsgirequest-post-signup-not-fo

Comment: Cannot assign "<class 'ProjectApp.models.ProjectModel'>": "comment.ProjectModel" must be a "ProjectModel" instance.

Gave me this error this time, Thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: my bad it was my mistake here:  replace this line form.ProjectModel = ProjectModel 
 with this line  form.ProjectModel = project . and also replace this return redirect(request, "/dashboard") by this return redirect("/dashboard")

Comment: @tahamaatof You're a life saver! Thank you very much!